# Overriding Phtml File in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, template, phtml

I am overriding this file

> vendor\magento\module-backend\view\adminhtml\templates\widget\grid\extended.phtml

I am overriding it in

> app\code\Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\templates\widget\grid\extended.phtml

Since it a template file i also need to create `backend_widget_grid.xml` at

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/layout/

with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="widget.extended">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">{Vendor}_{Module}::widget/grid/extended.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

But I am not sure if the `referenceBlock` or if the `backend_widget_grid.xml` name I am entering is incorrect since my edit doesn't show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to override a `admin` template but, you put it in `frontend` !

Try this:

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/adminhtml/layout/

instead of :

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/layout/

Comment: Thank you for the response and yes the path should be changed of the xml file but is there something incorrect with it because my edits still don't show

Comment: Put also the new `template` in adminhtml : `app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/adminhtml/templates/`

Comment: I uptaded the comment because I forgot to mention it. Thanks for the reminder but something else is wrong :/